# How can I fetch all events from all my calendars using EventKit and pyobjc

Tags: eventkit, pyobjc, apple-developer

I'm fairly new to the Apple Developer program and I'm trying to figure out some basic things.
One of them is to fetch all events from all my calendars. As far as I know this should be possible with the EventKit framework. As I'm developing in python I'm using pyobjc.
How can I achieve my wish? Do I need to authorize the access?

I figured out that I need an eventstore and I also managed to set up a predicate, but I can't see my calendars or events yet.

Comment: Could you show me the code you tried that failed to get the events?

Comment: @TeddyC this is the python code:

`from EventKit import EKEventStore
ek_store = EKEventStore.alloc().init()`

then `ek_store.calendars()` only contains one calendar which is not one of mine

Another thing I tried was

`pred_ = ek_store.predicateForEventsWithStartDate_endDate_calendars_(date_1, date_2, None)
all_events = ek_store.eventsMatchingPredicate_(pred_)`

where `date_1` and `date_2` are in NSDate format
but `all_events` was empty here